# Are these class variables?

Tags: ruby, class-variables

In the snippet below,

```
class MyClass
  class << self    
    @@variable1 = 'foo'

    def my_method
      @variable2 = 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

are `@@variable1` and `@variable2` class variables?  Said differently, is the above snippet equivalent to this one:

```
 class MyClass
    @@variable1 = 'foo'

    def self.my_method
      @@variable2 = 'bar'
    end
 end
```

EDITED

@suvankar, thanks for answering.  The second snippet was a typo and I edited it to include 'self'.  I'm actually not entirely sure that in the first snippet, variable2 is a class variable.  For example, if I load the first snippet into irb, and type:

```
  >> MyClass.class_variables
  => [@@variable1]

  >> MyClass.instance_variables
  => [@variable2]
```

So it seems like variable1 is a class variable (no surprise there). But variable2 is an instance variable of the class MyClass.

Comment: In snippet 1, you only have one `@` in `@variable2`, whereas in the irb output, you have two `@@` in `@@variable2`. Was that your intent?

Comment: Hey Peter, yes that was intentional.  The reason is @variable2 is inside "class << self" so it's not just a plain old instance variable.  I think it's called a class instance variable, but that's why I'm here to figure out.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that irb would show `@@variable2` when your code had `@variable2`. Could you double check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `@@variable1` is a class variable and `@variable2` is an instance variable of the class. The two snippets are not equivalent because `@@variable2` (only defined in snippet two) is also a class variable.

(Note: I assume that your irb output has a typo and that it should have included `@variable2` and only after invoking `MyClass.my_method`.)

Comment: You're right.  Variable2 was a typo.  I changed it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Answering to first question:**
yes,  variable1 and variable2 **class variables**

**Second question:**
Above two snippet are not same.

**Explanation:**

In the first snippet `'my_method'` is **class method** and
in the second snippet `'my_method'` is **instance method**.

Following snippet is similar to first snippet, where `my_method` is a class method of `MyClass`

```
class MyClass
    @@variable1 = 'foo'

    def self.my_method
      @@variable2 = 'bar'
    end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering suvankar, but check out my latest comment edit.